# Listings, problem with rendering embedded strings

Tags: listings

this is my style defined for C#:

```
\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}{
  language=[Sharp]C
  ,captionpos=b
  ,columns=fixed
  ,morekeywords={var,get,set}
  ,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily 
  ,keywordstyle=\color{blue}
  ,commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen}
  ,stringstyle=\color{BrickRed};
  ,breaklines=true
  ,tabsize=1
  ,showstringspaces=false
  ,showspaces=false
  ,showtabs=false
  ,breakatwhitespace=true
  ,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
  ,emph={double,bool,int,unsigned,char,true,false,void,get,set}
  ,emphstyle=\color{blue}
  ,lineskip={-1.5pt} % single line spacing
}
```

The problem is that for some reason, when the embedded strings are rendered, they look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(;";S;:;String;");
```

but should:

```
Console.WriteLine("S:String");
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tell-tale hint is the presence of multiple semicolons just before each "token" (syntactic unit of characters) involved in the string.

If you inspect your source code, you'll find the line `stringstyle=\color{BrickRed};`, which is telling `lstlisting` to add a semicolon and switch the color to `BrickRed` each time a token inside a string is typeset. Get rid of the semi-colon and the problem should be fixed.